# Unexpected Application Error! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode') In React

Tags: reactjs

I don't use any variable called 'encode'.
I use Vite + React to build my app. I also use Apache Echarts.
Locally, when running my application, or when doing npm run build, no errors appear.

But when deploying my application, I get this error on the screen.

```
Unexpected Application Error!
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')
     at e.mapDimensionsAll (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at x2 (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at or (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at e.<anonymous> (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at t.<anonymous> (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at BF (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at t.eachSeries (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at e.Wy (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
     at e.update (https://desarrollo.d2qwzq..........)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix it. The problem was in the minifier that Vite used. I have changed from Terser to ESbuild. The bundle is bigger, but at least it works

Before:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env
  },
  build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
      safari10:true,
      ie8:true,
      toplevel: true,
      module: true,
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
        reduce_funcs: true,
      },
      mangle: {
        properties: {
          regex: /^_/,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

After:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env
  }
})
```